# Spring boot microservices and syncrhonized schedulers

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, scheduling

I have a service which is deployed as microservice and a mongodb with some documents with "few" states, for example: READY, RUNNING, COMPLETED. I need to pick the documents with state "READY" and then process them. But with multiple instances running there is high possibility of processing the "duplicates". I have seen the below thread, but it is only concerned about one instance only picking up tasks.

[Spring boot Webservice / Microservices and scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068344/spring-boot-webservice-microservices-and-scheduling)

Above talks about solution using Hazlecast and mongodb. But what I am looking at is that all instances wait for the lock, get their own "documents (non-duplicates) and process them. I have checked the various documents and unfortunately I am not able to find any solution.

One of the option I thought is to introduce Kafka, where we can "assign" specific tasks to specific consumers. But before opting would like to see if we any solutions which can be implemented using simple methods such as database locks etc. Any pointers towards this are highly appreciated.

Comment: You read from MongoDB or a regular database or....

Comment: @Denium, from mongodb, otherwise could have used the RDBMS locks, I suppose you are pointing towards it, right?